# Конкретная java для sh скрипта

Tags: java

У меня есть два sh скрипта. Один для запуска требует java не младше 17, другой - не старше 16.
Как я могу определить конкретную версию для каждого скрипта, подскажите пожалуйста?

Я пробовал прописывать полный путь до папки java. Permission denied.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а что, собственно, не понятно в вопросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через выбор необходимой java каждый раз при запуске sh скрипта через update-alternatives.

сначала ввёл
update-alternatives --сonfig java и с помощью этого узнал пути установленных jdk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом добавил в скрипты следующие команды

```
update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java16-full-amd64/bin/java;
# для java 16

update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java17-full-amd64/bin/java;
# для java 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Какую Java запустить определяет переменная окружения `JAVA_HOME` и бинарник, перед строкой скрипта добавляешь `alias javac=/путь/до/17/bin/javac && JAVA_HOME=/путь/до/17й script1.sh` перед вторым соответственно `alias javac=/путь/до/16/bin/javac && JAVA_HOME=/путь/до/16й script2.sh` Ну и конечно посмотри что-бы PATH не перемешивался...

Comment: ни на что не повлияло, всё равно запускается базовая java

Comment: **посмотри что-бы PATH не перемешивался...** У тебя в PATH скорее всего прописан другой javac который подмешивается как основной... Посмотреть какой, можно через `which javac` Хотя по факту алиас должен был его переписать, видимо у тебя что-то не получается можно в начале скрипта прописать `javac -version` и посмотреть какая реальная версия попадает в скрипт.

Comment: По умолчанию alias работает только в интерактивной оболочке, а в скрипте - нет.